# Shortcode not accepting atts

Tags: shortcode

i have been working on a shortcode and I am having trouble passing $atts to it.

i can't figure out what i am doing wrong.

To say it another way,   i cannot update 'input_product_image_ID' to a different value from it's default value of 13 by inserting a new value into the shortcode.

for example this shortcode would still return 13,  not 12:

[product_picture input_product_image_ID="12"]

**My code:**

```
function article_image_insert_shortcode($atts) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'input_product_image_ID' => 13,
   ), $atts));


$product_id = $input_product_image_ID;


// get product page url which is stored as caption 
$product_page_url           = get_post_field('post_excerpt', $product_id );

// get and insert image 
$product_image              = wp_get_attachment_image( $product_id , full_size );

// get image alt text which serves as the image title 
$product_description_alt    = get_post_meta($product_id , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);


// get image caption where link is stored


$thumb_img = get_post( get_post($product_id) );

// assign caption 

$product_aff_url            = $thumb_img->post_content;


$article_image_insert_shortcode = /* do some stuff */;

return $article_image_insert_shortcode;


}

add_shortcode('product_picture', 'article_image_insert_shortcode');
```

Comment: Yes because you are defining `input_product_image_ID` to `13` in shortcode function itself.

Comment: im not sure that is it,   shouldn't that value update from shortcode atts?

Comment: for example, this shortcode defines $atts similarly to mine, and yet it still updates `function random_picture($atts) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'width' => 400,
      'height' => 200,
   ), $atts));
return '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/'. $width . '/'. $height . '" />';
} add_shortcode('picture', 'random_picture');`

Comment: Okay, use attribute name in lower case `input_product_image_id` instead of `input_product_image_ID`

Comment: thanks that did it---  I can't use caps like that in atts?  in any case I appreciate your help!!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Roberthue never use `extract()`, it is prone to fail

Comment: @PeterVijeh Apart from the problem Robert pointed out, never use `extract()`. It will fail. Check the Shortcode API on how to properly construct a shortcode

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers in the comments from RH, I found this in the codex (it's kind of burried deep):

- Shortcode attribute names are always converted to lowercase before
  they are passed into the handler function. Values are untouched.

This is from:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode#Parameters